# How to set an NSDictionary user default through a command line argument?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

It's possible to set [User Defaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AboutPreferenceDomains/AboutPreferenceDomains.html) in a Cocoa app by passing them on the command line as arguments like:

`> SomeApp -key value`

This sets the default `"key"` to `"value"` in the `NSArgumentDomain`.

Array defaults can be set by doing something like:

`> SomeApp -key (element1,element2)`

I've found that this will set an empty dictionary:

`> SomeApp -key {}`

... but I can't figure out how to set a dictionary containing elements. How can I set an NSDictionary user default through a command line argument?

Answer (score 4):

It turns out the proper syntax is:
`> SomeApp -key {key1=value1;key2=value2;}`

The array and dictionary syntax is similar to the output of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` values when printed through `NSLog()`.

Comment: Nice, I'm glad you got this worked out. Probably useful to someone...!

Comment: There should be a ';' after 'value2' too, or the NSDefaults will get an empty dictionary

Comment: Updated the answer to include ';' after value2. Thanks Gavin!